# AgGrid: how do I get an instance of a custom cell renderer?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a custom input cell renderer:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-ag-input-cell-renderer',
  template: `<my-input [(ngModel)]="_model"></my-input>`
})
export class InputCellRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  public params: any = {};

  _model;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;

    this._model = params.value;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  getInputValue(): string {
    return this._model;
  }
}
```

Now I need a way to access `getInputValue` so I can retrieve a value from it.

I tried `this.gridApi.getCellRendererInstances()`, but it returns an array of `DynamicAgNg2Component` components and the method is not accessible through it.

Is there any way to do so? My ag-grid version is `24.1.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem. If you figure out which render it is within that list then call `getFrameworkComponentInstance()` it should return the component which you can then call your desired method.

[More info](http://54.222.217.254/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#accessing-cell-renderer-instances)

In my case, I used it on the a custom cellEditor but it should work similarly on the custom cellRenderer (swapping `getCellEditorInstances()` for `getCellRendererInstances()`)

```js
const cellEditor = this.gridApi.getCellEditorInstances()[0].getFrameworkComponentInstance();

cellEditor.myMethod()
```